# How to convert 'from Queue import Queue, Empty' from Python 2 to Python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing

I'm converting a source code written in Python 2 to Python 3 and I stumbled into this:

```
from Queue import Queue, Empty
```

I changed it to:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Empty
```

But this gives me an exception:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Empty'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `Queue` is `queue` in python 3.

Comment: `from queue import Queue, Empty`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) is used for processes, don't let the capitalization confuse you. [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/queue.html), which was renamed to [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html) in Python 3, is for threads.

Both [`Empty`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html#queue.Empty) and [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) are located in the `queue` module, so grab them from there.