# No module named 'Queue'

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-import

My import of Python modules

```
import Queue
from threading import Thread
import time
```

But when I run code

```
File "b1.py", line 3, in <module>
    import Queue
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Queue'
```

I have seen similar threads on SO,but nothings works for me

```
/usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
milenko@milenko-System-Product-Name:~$ python --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
```

If I change to

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

there is no import problem.But than I have this

```
AttributeError: 'Queue' object has no attribute 'join'
```

What should I try next?

Comment: you can try `import queue`

Comment: To explain: On Python 2, the module is named `Queue`, on Python 3, it was renamed to follow PEP8 guidelines (all lowercase for module names), making it `queue`. The *class* remains `Queue` on all versions (following PEP8).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Unfortunately, the problem described there is best answered by the accepted answer. The `requests` module already tries importing from `queue`, then falling back to `Queue` if that fails. Their problem wasn't about Python version at all. The suggestion to use `multiprocessing.Queue` is a truly terrible answer (you'd have to monkey-patch `requests`, and it would involve slowing down everything, and breaking if unpicklable stuff was involved); every answer to that question *except* the accepted one was posted by people not paying attention to the OP's actual problem.

Comment: @ShadowRanger so you're suggesting reopening? that would fly by me since this particular question is clearer. your comment (with the PEP8 stuff) would make a nice answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I guess? That question is kind of a terrible duplicate target; most of the questions targeting it as a duplicate are like this one, not issues with naming personally written modules `queue.py` (the ultimate problem there), but trying `import Queue` on Python 3 (the problem here).

Comment: @ShadowRanger [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150948/how-to-convert-from-queue-import-queue-empty-from-python-2-to-python-3/41151032#41151032) is an appropriate duplicate target. Though, since I believe your answer here is better, I'll close it as a dupe of this one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On Python 2, the module is named `Queue`, on Python 3, it [was renamed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#pep-8-violations-done) to follow [PEP8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) (all lowercase for module names), making it `queue`. The *class* remains `Queue` on all versions (following PEP8).

Typically, the way you'd write version portable imports would be to do:

```
try:
    import queue           # Python 3 import
except ImportError:
    import Queue as queue  # If queue missing, we're on Py2, import Py2 as Py3 name
```

Comment: This doesnt work for Python 3.6, since it now throws a `ModuleNotFoundError` instead of the `ImportError`. Changing to `except ModuleNotFoundError` would then again not work for older versions, since this exception type did not exist there. Checkmate :D

Comment: @Jeronimo: It works fine. [`ModuleNotFoundError` is a subclass of `ImportError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ModuleNotFoundError), so catching `ImportError` also catches `ModuleNotFoundError`. `ImportError` isn't as fine-grained (e.g. it can't tell you the problem is a name-shadowing module, rather than a lack of a module), but it will work. Also, since I prioritized the Py3 name, the only place `ImportError` would be raised is Py2, so it's doubly fine.

Comment: Ah ok, you're right. I thought to remember this causing an error in my code recently, but I can't find it right now, so something else must have been the source then...

Comment: File "main.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.queue = queue()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @John: Reread the first paragraph of my answer. The module `queue` (which is the name the code above uses regardless of Python version, as we alias the Python 2 name to the Python 3 name) contains the class `Queue` (which is the same on all versions). You want `self.queue = queue.Queue()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the following for Python 2.7

```
from Queue import Queue, Empty
```

I changed only the module name to lower case, and it worked fine with Python 3 like

```
from queue import Queue, Empty
```